# How to make cursor go to new line while typing on pressing enter in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I am taking input from an input field and updating it in the canvas using onkeyup

```
var inputText = document.getElementById("input");
var text = new createjs.Text();
text.set({
  text: inputText.value,
  textAlign: "center",
  textBaseline: "middle",
  x: 100,
  y: 100
});
stage.addChild(text);
stage.update();
inputText.onkeyup = function(){
  text.set({
    text: inputText.value
  })
  stage.update();
}
```

How to make this text wrap to next line when I press enter while typing?

Answer (score 1):

`input` element is single-line, you can achieve it by using a `textarea`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q71vL1zh/) is a simple example illustrating the point